# Whe LocalDateTime throws exception when try to parse line using DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, date-formatting

I try to user LocalDateTime and DateTimeFormatter and try to parse this String:

```
2020-04-28 and time: 12:37:49.863
```

But throws DateTimeParseException

This is code fragment:

```
String line = "2020-04-28 and time: 12:37:49.863";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd 'and time: 'hh:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(line, formatter);
```

Why does it occours?

Comment: `HH` instead of `hh` maybe?

Comment: What is the exception message? Also are you sure `'and time: '` is supposed to be in there? How does the formatter know it is supposed to be taken literally?

Comment: @smac89 so, before this, I successfully used this formatter to format LocalDateTime value. So, this is correct and time usage in pattern. So, this pattern works for write value, but doesn't work for parse value..

Comment: If you want to use `hh` instead of `HH`, I think you have to also use `a` for AM or PM - `"2020-04-28 and time: 12:37:49.863 AM"` and `"yyyy-MM-dd 'and time:' hh:mm:ss.SSS a"`.

Comment: @andrewjames  yes, you are correct, I didn't know about this difference, thanks

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thanks

Comment: @smac89 The single quotes tell the formatter that `and time: ` is literal text, not format pattern letters. Good question.